# PHP DateTime parsing time instead of date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to prepare a MySQL query in PHP. My problem is PHP treats dates differently to MySQL.

In MySQL '2000' is the year 2000, in PHP it's 8 PM.

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date1->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 2000-01-01 00:00:00
$date2 = new DateTime('2000-01');
echo $date2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 2000-01-01 00:00:00

// This gets 8 PM instead of the year 2000
$date3 = new DateTime('2000');
echo $date3->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 2014-07-14 20:00:00

$date4 = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", '2000');
echo $date4->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

I only want the time to be parsed if it is included after the date.

Is there a way to tell it to prioritize parsing the year over the time in PHP?

Comment: classic example of **Garbage in, garbage out (GIGO)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect `DateTime` to parse a date in a particular format if you're only going to pass a year.

However, you can clear all the other date fields by passing an exclamation point as part of the format:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y', '2000');
echo $date->format('r'); // Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00: +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP `DateTime` [construct](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) first parameter is a date/time string. Valid formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). For your case, those will be [Compound Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php).

You should not just toss around strings formatted in whatever way possible. You/developer is the only one who knows precisely in what format input date will be and that means, developer is responsible to sanitize/validate data required for input in `DateTime` class, beforehand.

tl;dr No, there is no way to prioritize parsing built inside `DateTime` class. You do that with your own code.